# Creating a shareable link to a document that opens in Office for desktop, not Office Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, share, links

There is a feature in SharePoint Online where you can select a document and choose 'Copy URL' to generate a shareable link to a document.

Unfortunately, by default, SharePoint is configured to make the document open on Office Online when a user clicks this URL. I need a way of creating a URL that opens the document on the user's client, not Office Online.

Does anybody know if this can be achieved? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't set Shared Links to open directly in Client Application. You will have to manually create a link in below format and share it to open in client application.

The following will open in the client directly:

https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/WordDoc1.docx

This link will prompt user to open in client application:

[ms-word:ofe|u|https://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/WordDoc1.docx](http://ms-word:ofe%7Cu%7Chttps://someurl.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/WordDoc1.docx)

Comment: Hi, this is quite the unfortunate limitation. I assume this is still the case. Does that mean that applications putting files in sharepoint would have to use a permission-based sharing model and can't use URL-based sharing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to have this functionality within a single document library:

In library settings click on Advanced, you will see : [image]

you can set the default behaviour to open in Client application (Word, Excel etc) - I have mine set to open in browser by default.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it clearer in my post. I already have this feature enabled which works fine when a user is viewing a document library and clicks on a document. However, if I select the document and choose 'copy URL' to create a shareable link, the link still directs the user to Office Online.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no worries.

So the link currently created looks like - https://mysite.sharepoint.com/subsite/dev/Shared%20Documents/file_name.xlsx?d=w732427edb5f64c25bb8422507c5f70ad

You could create a calculated column to strip the url back to -

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/subsite/dev/Shared%20Documents/file_name.xlsx

Losing everything from the ? to the right.

Have you experience of creating calculated columns? Or formula in excel?

You will probably need the calc column to create the url, then another column to hyperlink the Url - which you can then display in the doc lib - when users click on your created link, the document will then open in the relevant application